# Filter Out NULL value via Pig

Tags: null, row, apache-pig

I have table which i read via following.

```
 A = load 'customer' using PigStorage('|');
```

In customer following are some of the row

```
7|Ron|ron@abc.com
8|Rina  
9|Don|dmes@xyz.com
9|Don|dmes@xyz.com
10|Maya|maya@cnn.com

11|marry|mary@abc.com
```

When i use following....

```
B = DISTINCT A;
A_CLEAN = FILTER B by ($0 is not null) AND ($1 is not null) AND ($2 is not null);
```

it removes 
8|Rina as well

How to remove null rows via Pig?

Is there a way i can try
    A_CLEAN = filter B by not IsNULL()???

I am new to pig so not sure what i shuld put inside IsNULL...

Thanks

A_CLEAN = filter B by not IsEmpty(B);

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
A = LOAD 'customer' USING PigStorage('|');
B = DISTINCT A;
A_CLEAN = FILTER B BY NOT(($0 IS NULL) AND ($1 IS NULL) AND ($2 IS NULL));
DUMP A_CLEAN;
```

This will produce the output:

(8,Rina  ) 
(7,Ron,ron@abc.com) 
(9,Don,dmes@xyz.com) 
(10,Maya,maya@cnn.com) 
(11,marry,mary@abc.com)

In PIG, you cannot test a tuple for emptiness.

Comment: This worked for me: FILTER B BY (($0 IS NOT NULL) AND ($1 IS NOT NULL) AND ($2 IS NOT NULL));

Answer (score 0):

```
 Tarun, instead AND condition why can't you put OR condition.
        A_CLEAN = FILTER B by ($0 is not null) OR ($1 is not null) OR ($2 is not null);
 This will remove all the null rows and retain if any columns is not empty. 
 Can you try and let me know if this works for your all conditions?
```

UPDATE:
I don't know why IsEmpty() is not working for you, its working for me.
IsEmpty will work only with bag, so i converted all the fields to bag and test the emptiness. see the below working code.

```
input.txt
7|Ron|ron@abc.com
8|Rina
9|Don|dmes@xyz.com
9|Don|dmes@xyz.com
10|Maya|maya@cnn.com

11|marry|mary@abc.com

PigSCript:
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage('|');
B = DISTINCT A;
A_CLEAN = FILTER B BY NOT IsEmpty(TOBAG($0..));
DUMP A_CLEAN;

Output:
(8,Rina  )
(7,Ron,ron@abc.com)
(9,Don,dmes@xyz.com)
(10,Maya,maya@cnn.com)
(11,marry,mary@abc.com)
```

For your another question, its a simple math calculation

```
In case of AND, 
8|Rina
 will be treated as
 ($0 is not null) AND ($1 is not null) AND ($2 is not null)
 (true) AND (true) AND (false)
 (false) -->so this record will be skipped by Filter command

In case of OR, 
8|Rina
 will be treated as
 ($0 is not null) OR ($1 is not null) OR ($2 is not null)
 (true) OR (true) OR (false)
 (true) -->so this record will be included into the relation by Filter command

In case of empty record, 
<empty record>
  will be treated as
  ($0 is not null) OR ($1 is not null) OR ($2 is not null)
  (false) OR (false) OR (false)
  (false) -->so this record will be skipped by Filter command
```

Comment: Yes...First one worked...not IsEmpty did not work. Not understanding logic here ...as AND should work as that what we are looking all three column should be empty...Thank you